# How to make same height map effect like in AwesomeBump?

Tags: texturing, displacement

In Awesomebump height map add kind of volume effect.
[image]

I tried to recrate this effect with displacement modifier and microdisplacement.
Result with displacement modifier and height map is just ugly
[image]

Microdisplacement variant looks way better but for some  reasons unknown to me 
faces apeears disconnected.[image]

**So, question is --- how to recreate this volume effect in blender7**

Here is my blender file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_-tV3odolwlQ3NYb0pjXy1ENXc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Parallax (occlusion) mapping is probably what you are looking for. If you do a quick search in blenderartists you should be able to find some node groups that will work pretty well

Comment: Sebastián Mestre, thank you, I gonna google it right now.